# Dúvida com Parser XML

Tags: android, simplexml, simplexml-load-string

Tenho um projeto que usa Jsoup para realizar o parser de um xml e estou mudando a implementação para Retrofit e SimpleXML, porém a estrutura do xml varia no bloco Content, onde pode vim somente uma String com o conteúdo ou vim uma foto, legenda...

Pesquisei e não achei nada que pudesse me ajudar a realizar o parse nessa estrutura mesmo usando um Converter.

Alguém saberia como pode ser feito o parse desse conteúdo?

```
<item>
    <title>
        Lorem ipsum dolor
    </title>
    <content>
        <![CDATA[
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ultrices varius hendrerit. Proin eu mattis nunc, ac tempor metus. Nunc sagittis metus sit amet nulla pellentesque, ut laoreet nisi tempor. Nullam at mauris mattis, placerat ante id, dignissim ex. Praesent ut efficitur dui. Vivamus venenatis risus et eros malesuada, in suscipit nisi consequat. Integer vel libero non nunc molestie eleifend. Mauris quis venenatis felis. Mauris dignissim sem ut felis bibendum, sed imperdiet leo accumsan. Vivamus eu sem sit amet augue rhoncus ultricies a vitae quam. Pellentesque sollicitudin fermentum ligula vitae blandit. Duis ut urna consectetur, vulputate turpis eget, maximus diam. Nunc hendrerit neque accumsan pellentesque ornare. Sed mattis metus sed erat convallis dictum. Curabitur ac libero eget dui tincidunt tincidunt.
        ]]>
    </content>
    <pubDate>Fri, 07 Oct 2016 15:39:00 -0200</pubDate>
</item>
<item>
    <title>
        Lorem ipsum dolor 2
    </title>
    <content>
        <photo>
        http://servicos.imagens/noticias/201610/F00031834.jpg
        </photo>
        <credit>Lorem</credit>
        <legend>
        Os participantes receberam orientação sobre condução segura, com uma aula teórica pela manhã e prática de pilotagem durante a tarde
        </legend>
        <![CDATA[
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ultrices varius hendrerit. Proin eu mattis nunc, ac tempor metus. Nunc sagittis metus sit amet nulla pellentesque, ut laoreet nisi tempor. Nullam at mauris mattis, placerat ante id, dignissim ex. Praesent ut efficitur dui. Vivamus venenatis risus et eros malesuada, in suscipit nisi consequat. Integer vel libero non nunc molestie eleifend. Mauris quis venenatis felis. Mauris dignissim sem ut felis bibendum, sed imperdiet leo accumsan. Vivamus eu sem sit amet augue rhoncus ultricies a vitae quam. Pellentesque sollicitudin fermentum ligula vitae blandit. Duis ut urna consectetur, vulputate turpis eget, maximus diam. Nunc hendrerit neque accumsan pellentesque ornare. Sed mattis metus sed erat convallis dictum. Curabitur ac libero eget dui tincidunt tincidunt.
        ]]>
    </content>
    <pubDate>Fri, 07 Oct 2016 15:38:06 -0200</pubDate>
</item>
```